# Django cms editor 3.0.3 and HTML attributes getting removed

Tags: django

I am using cms-editor 3.0.3 when i am editing my page and the tags like "placeholder" and "onclick" parameter getting removed. 
as i have pasted the following code:

```
<div class="form-group"><input class="form-control" id="PhnNo" name="user-req-phone" placeholder="Please enter your phone" type="text" /></div>

<div class="col-sm-12"><button class="btn btn-primary btn-block mt20 " onclick="trip(1)" style="width: 100px; float: left;" type="submit">Submit</button></div>
```

after saving this code it is automatically convert like this:

```
<div class="form-group"><input class="form-control" id="PhnNo" name="user-req-phone" type="text" /></div>



<div class="col-sm-12"><button class="btn btn-primary btn-block mt20 " style="width: 100px; float: left;" type="submit">Submit</button></div>
```

Please provide me the solution by which i can resolve this problem.